# How to exclude list of items from Get-ChildItem result in powershell?

Tags: powershell

I want to get list of files (actually number of files) in a path, recursively, excluding certain types:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Recurse | ? { $_.Name -notlike "*.cs" -and $_.Name -notlike "*.tt" }
```

but I have a long list of exclusions (to name a few):

```
@("*.cs", "*.tt", "*.xaml", "*.csproj", "*.sln", "*.xml", "*.cmd", "*.txt")
```

How to get the list using this form:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Recurse | ? { <# what to put here ?#> }
```

?

Answer (score 69, accepted):

This works too:

```
get-childitem $path -recurse -exclude *.cs,*.tt,*.xaml,*.csproj,
  *.sln,*.xml,*.cmd,*.txt
```

Note that -include only works with -recurse or a wildcard in the path. (actually it works all the time in 6.1 pre 2)

Also note that using both -exclude and -filter will not list anything, without -recurse or a wildcard in the path.

-include and -literalpath also seem problematic in PS 5.

There's also a bug with -include and -exclude with the path at the root "", that displays nothing.  In unix it gives an error.

Excluding a directory like "foo3" (not the full path) is challenging.  It doesn't seem to work with -recurse or -filter.  You can pipe to a 2nd get-childitem.

```
get-childitem -exclude foo3 | get-childitem -recurse -filter file*
```

Comment: @pinepain, I think it's simpler, one-liner, less verbose, thus differentiated from (previously) accepted answer.

Comment: Thanks for noting this: "Also note that using both -exclude and -filter will not list anything, without -recurse or a wildcard in the path." But can you explain why it is like that? I had issues in my code because of that behavior and I only figured that out by finding your post.

Comment: @Ravior I don't know, but I believe it's fixed in powershell 7.

Answer (score 38):

You can supply exclusions to `Get-ChildItem` with the `-exclude` parameter:

```
$excluded = @("*.cs", "*.tt", "*.xaml", "*.csproj", "*.sln", "*.xml", "*.cmd", "*.txt")
get-childitem -path $path -recurse -exclude $excluded
```

Comment: Thanks. The insight here is to be able to pass an array to -exclude

Answer (score 12):

Here is how you would do it using a Where-Object cmdlet:

```
$exclude = @(".cs", ".tt", ".xaml", ".csproj", ".sln", ".xml", ".cmd", ".txt")
Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Recurse | Where-Object { $exclude -notcontains $_.Extension }
```

If you do not want directories to be returned in the results as well, then use this:

```
$exclude = @(".cs", ".tt", ".xaml", ".csproj", ".sln", ".xml", ".cmd", ".txt")
Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Recurse | Where-Object { (-not $_.PSIsContainer) -and ($exclude -notcontains $_.Extension) }
```

Comment: What if I want to exclude a specific file?

Answer (score 4):

```
Set-Location C:\

$ExcludedcDirectory = "Windows|Program|Visual|Trend|NVidia|inet"
$SearchThis = Get-ChildItem -Directory | where Name -NotMatch $ExcludedcDirectory

$OutlookFiles = foreach ($myDir in $SearchThis) {    
    $Fn = Split-Path $myDir.fullname
    $mypath = "Get-ChildItem -Path $Fn\*.pst, *.ost -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue" 

     Invoke-Expression "$mypath"
}
$OutlookFiles.FullName
```

Comment: Please explain your solution.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this using Where-Object:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Recurse | Where-Object { $_.Extension -notin @("*.cs", "*.tt", "*.xaml", "*.csproj", "*.sln", "*.xml", "*.cmd", "*.txt")}
```

Answer (score 0):

Compare `dll` files of two directories, `$src_dir` and `$dest_dir`, and list files not existing in `$src`

```
Get-ChildItem (Join-Path $src_dir "*.dll") -Exclude (Get-ChildItem (Join-Path $dest_dir "*.dll") -File | %{$_.Name})
```