# Exclude folders for the reduces the size of images

Tags: powershell

I have a script that reduces the size of images in folders and subfolders. However, I would like to exclude some of the folders.

I have find the parameter `$source_listephotos = Get-ChildItem $source -Recurse | where {$_.FullName -notmatch $exclude_list}` but it allows exclude one folder and not several.

```
$source = "U:\TEST\Compression\images"
$exclude_list = @('Imprimerie')

$source_listephotos = Get-ChildItem $source -Recurse | where {$_.FullName -notmatch $exclude_list}
```

Do you have a solution ?

Comment: Create your excludelist as a string like so :  'Imprimerie|Imprimerie1abc'...also i would suggest matching on $_.name because fullname would match the entire path. consider combining your where clause with $_.psiscontainer  -eq $true

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to exclude list of items from Get-ChildItem result in powershell?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19207991/how-to-exclude-list-of-items-from-get-childitem-result-in-powershell)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [match/notmach](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators) operators use regular expressions (regex) so the easiest solution to fix your code is to use [alternation](http://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) with pipe symbol for your folders' list.

```
$source = "U:\TEST\Compression\images"
[regex] $exclude_list = “(Imprimerie|TestAnotherName)”

$source_listephotos = Get-ChildItem $source -Recurse | where {$_.FullName -notmatch $exclude_list}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have tried and my script works as I want

Answer (score 2):

you can use the exclusion list on get-childitem

```
$source_listephotos = Get-ChildItem $source -Recurse -exclude $exclude_list| where {$_.FullName}
```

Comment: The where clause is obsolete then, and  to differentiate the list from the RegEx variant `$exclude_list = @('Imprimerie','otherfoler')`